# How do I call WCF web service method with jQuery?

Tags: wcf, web-services, asmx

This should be half an hours work but has turned into two days. All I want to do is have a WCF service that can be called via a ServiceReference and also by Jquery.

These two tutorials only work for jquery:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/132809/Calling-WCF-Services-using-jQuery

This one looked like it would work for both but actually it demonstrates one method that can be called by jquery and one by a service refererence.

I thought I would give WCF a go as it is supposed to replace ASMX but actually, for all its bells and whistles, creates more problems than solutions.

With an ASMX web service I could call it by a Web/ServiceReference or from javascript right out the box with no messing about.

Can anyone show me how to create and configure a service so that all the methods can be consumed via jquery or via adding a service reference.

Comment: WCF does so much more than an ASMX web service, but if all you need is an ASMX web service, why use WCF?

Answer (score 0):

May be this [tutorial](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/sridhar_subra/consuming-wcf-asmx-rest-service-using-jquery/) will help you in identifying which one is better and why.

Apart `ASMX` Web services can only be invoked by `HTTP`. While `WCF` Service can be invoked by any protocol (like http, tcp etc.) and any transport type.

Also check out [this](http://keithelder.net/2008/10/17/wcf-vs-asmx-webservices/).